# Wicket Parameters Passing

Tags: java, parameter-passing, wicket

I am new in Wicket. I have little problem. I have Course frame where I get Course details like id, name, department from user with form and the same about Student frame, gets details from user with form. And I need to send these course and student objects to my main page to work with this data like assigning courses to students and etc. But I do not know how to pass Course and Student objects to main page. I could not do it with setResponsePage, because user should not go to the main page as immediately he submit new Course or Student. I mean user should be able to create several Student or Course objects one after another without going to main page. 
I tried create Arraylists in Student and Course Pages, fill these ArrayLists with  objects and then access to these ArrayLists from main page, but it seems that accessing other page's Data Structure is problem in Java or maybe I do it false.

Can you help me, give me advice how to figure out this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Please explain the work flow, e.g. the user lands to the home page then clicks here and there to select the Course and Student and then I want to send those to PageB. "Main page" means nothing to us.

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand, we do not know what exactly you want to accomplish.

Comment: Never pass arguments as big objects (Course etc), use Model<T>'s. many examples in documentation

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is some sort of data layer, like a database or minimum a session implementation in which you store your data that needs to be shared between multiple pages.

Try Session.get().setMetaData(...) to store your information and Session.get().getMetaData(...) to retrieve it. This suffices for transient data passing needs during the lifetime of a user session, for everything else you have to use a database or some sort of persistence layer in your architecture.

The session is accessible from all wicket pages.